# How to send data to another server?

Tags: php, httprequest

I want to save my data to another server.

When I get data in my page, I want send them to another server and in the destination, I want to write them on a file.

What should I do in both source and destination server php pages?

Comment: Have you tried something so far ? we are not going to build a program from scratch to you. You need to provide something that we can help you out. Without this, your question is unclear.

Comment: I get inputs from users. Then I save my data on my first server. Now I want to save the data on another server too.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. **Work Queues**

You send a request to a work queue, for example [Beanstalkd](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd), telling it what's to be done. It's on you then how you should craft the request. For example:

```
{
    "action": "delete",
    "entity": {
        "type": "User",
        "id":   1
    }
}
```

2. **HTTP Request**

You just send an HTTP request (with any library you want, or just even curl native functions) to the URL you wish and send the relative information in any format you want. It can be JSON, or even just form data.

This is how you'd do it with [GuzzleHttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$client->request(
    'POST',
    'http://domain.tld',
    [
        'body' => [
            'action' => 'delete',
            'entity' => [
                'type' => 'User',
                'id'   => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```